# How to store wordpress based and hand coded site on same hosting?

Tags: wordpress, dns, hosting

I hand coded restaurant website and my boss wants me to make another website for exporting company, which will be based on WordPress.  I don't want to pay for another domain name , so my questions is:
 1) Can I store restaurant website on  hosting  A with domain ( www.y.com) and can I store WordPress based site on hosing B  with domain (www.trade.y.com)?

2)Or would it be possible to store WordPress based and not WordPress based website on same sharing hosting?

Comment: 1) yes, of course. 2) usually yes, but it depends on hosting service

Answer (score 0):

You could use multi Site concept in Wordpress using a plugin called {WPMU}.

Install that plugin and just include the below piece of code.

### Settings:

/* Multisite */
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);

Include in WP-config file.

Then may you can use multiple sites with single domain..